# Angular datatables not rendering html in table and modal

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing an issue with Angular datatables which shows only plain text in my table and bootstrap modal as well
My data includes html tags such break lines and bold but it's not rendering and showing as plain text only
Tried few troubleshoot but not able to figure it out

***HTML***

```
    <div id="crudmodalx" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <form method="post" ng-submit="viewData()">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="text-secondary">Details <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i></h4>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- -->
          <ul ng-repeat="name in namesView">
            <div class="card mb-3 bg-light">
              <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img ng-src="uploads/default.png" class="img-fluid rounded-start" style="height: 20rem;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-primary">{{name.agent}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      <i class="fa fa-hospital-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><b> Facility:</b> {{name.facility}}<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-venus-mars" aria-hidden="true"></i><b> Gender:</b> {{name.gender}}<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i><b> Gender:</b> {{name.nationality}}<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-hospital-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><b> Specialty: </b>{{name.specialty}}<br>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">Known Expertise:</div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">{{name.known_expertise}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-white bg-danger mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">Restrictions: </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">{{name.other_restrictions}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
      var app = angular.module('crudApp', ['datatables']);
      app.controller('crudController', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.success = false;

        $scope.error = false;

        
        //view modal
        $scope.viewModal = function(id) {
          var modal_popup = angular.element('#crudmodalx');
          modal_popup.modal('show');

        };

        //###########

        $scope.viewData = function(id) {
          $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "view.php",
            data: {
              'id': id,
              'action': 'viewData'
            }
          }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.namesView = data;
            $scope.viewModal();
          });
        };

      });
    </script>
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated

Comment: Angular != AngularJs. I removed the Angular tag

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for solution, this issue can be resolved by adding `ngSanitize` in the Angular `var app = angular.module('crudApp', ['datatables', 'ngSanitize']);`
 and in the html `<span ng-bind-html="name.facility">{{name.facility}}</span>` 
 also I have added `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>` 
 and everything works just as desired